# Form showing only after async tasks finished

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I've got this custom `Task` code:

```
public static async Task Run(this CustomForm parent, Action action)
{
    parent.Enabled = false;
    using (Caricamento form = new Caricamento())
    {
        form.TopLevel = true;
        form.TopMost = true;
        form.Show();
        await Task.Run(action);
    }
    parent.Enabled = true;
}
```

The gif animation and the text inside the form just won't properly load until the `async` task finished .

```
    ListMessaggi listForm = new ListMessaggi(ListMessaggi.Tipo.Entrata);
    listForm.FormClosing += (o, args) =>
    {
        if (this.Controls.Count == 2)
        {
            args.Cancel = true;
        }
    };

    listForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    listForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    listForm.TopLevel = false;
    panel.Controls.Add(listForm);
    listForm.Show();
```

And then, in the form which shows up upon `listForm.Show()` method call I've got: [image]

Finally, this the result showing while the async task is running:
[image]

How can I improve the code to make things work properly?

Comment: The "best" way to improve it, would be to make `Run` method take a `Func<Task>` instead of an `Action`, and then just await it's `Invoke` method, instead of using `Task.Run`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner paste some code and I'll accept your answer if it works.

Comment: Odds are that what I have in mind won't jut be as simple as it sounds, which is why I didn't post it as an answer.  You may have to re-architect a large portion of your application to get it to work. I'll need some more information about what you are actually trying to do (and why) .Can you give an example of what kind of stuff you are doing in `UpdateGrid`?  Its name implies that it is doing something with the UI, but doing it inside `Task.Run` means it is executing outside of the UI thread. That's *probably* where the lockup is coming from.

Comment: @BradleyUffner UpdateGrid actually accesses business methods that interface with the database, such as `myModel.GetAll()` *which returns `List<myModel>` * and `List<myModel>` will be assigned to the datagrid with the appropriate filtering and such. `UpdateGrid` will be called on form load, and on dialogs close-ups (like Edit item, on `FormClosing` of the form that has opened the grid will be refreshed trough the same method)

Comment: My entire application follows this logic, and at this point I am trying to implement asyncronous loading to avoid UI lockout

Comment: UpdateGrid method: https://imgur.com/a/jxQnb8R

Comment: So the only asynchronous work you are doing with this is waiting for data from the database?  If so, this shouldn't be too bad.  You just need to update your data access calls to use `async` / `await`.  If properly implemented, it will get rid of *all* the `Task.Run` calls, and all those `InvokeRequired` checks you are doing.  Are you using ADO.NET, or EntityFramework for data access (or something else)?.

Comment: I am using `SqlDataReader` for data access layer. I like to have top control on queries and always avoid EF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the additional information you provided in the comments, I think that you should try to convert your code to entirely use `async` / `await`.  This will involve converting all your ADO.NET functions to the new [async methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/asynchronous-programming) added to ADO in .NET 4.5.  This will should eliminate all the `Task.Run` calls, as well as the messy `InvokeRequired` and `BeginInvoke` calls that you are doing to marshal control back to the UI thread.

I think you will find that, if properly implemented, you won't even need the special `Run` extension method; you will be able to have all your code in-line, just as in "traditional" .net development.

For example, you could use code like this to responsively load data, without locking the UI, in a form's `Load` event.

```
public async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var data = await _dataProvider.GetSomeDataFromTheDatabase(aTotallyMadeUpVariable);
    this.MyDataGrid.DataSource = data;
}
```

The exact same pattern works for the event handlers on comboboxes and buttons.

---

As a side note, event handlers in WinForms is practically the only place that `async void` methods are legitimately valid.  Everything else, including `async` methods called from *within* event handler, should be `Task` returning functions.

---

As a bit more of a "primer" on `async` / `await`, this is how it avoids blocking the UI thread in my example above.

The `async` modifier on a function acts as a marker to the compiler to convert the method in to a state-machine.  The compile will segment the code in the method, breaking it up at each `await` call, in to separate states.  When the function is called, the first state is run (up to where the `await` is), and then the function returns to the caller.  When the function that is being awaitted returns, the code after it (in the next state) is invoked as a continuation.  Any data that is shared between the states, such as local variables, is moved off to an object that is passed in to each state's continuation.

Comment: No, the entire purpose of the  `async` / `await` pattern is allow the UI to not block the UI thread, and keep the application responsive, without having to deal with threading issues.  Its entire purprose in life is to do *exactly* what you want to do here.

Comment: I added a little "async primer" blob to the bottom of the answer that should give you a start as understanding the basics of how that avoids blocking the UI.  The full details are kind of complex, and go beyond what I can explain in this answer.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/SyXmpvh This is the result. It works, however the UI of the loading form gets locked at a certain point and it doesn't spin until the form has loaded entirely. Code used: https://imgur.com/a/IS3QJ4i, Method code: https://imgur.com/a/GC3wg7Q

Comment: You still have some blocking calls in `GetInEntrata` that need to be converted to their async counterparts.  First one I see is that you need to change `connection.Open` to `await connection.OpenAsync`.

Comment: Also, if you need to post code in the future, [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) is much better than screenshots.

Comment: Done that. Now the Loading UI won't spin at all. I've got no more async calls to add in the business method.

Comment: Can you put your entire `GetInEntrata` method up on pastebin for me?

Comment: I found the error being more methods being called in the reader loop. Thanks, you solved my issue

Comment: what is `Allegato.Manager.GetAllegatiMessaggi((int)reader["Id"])`?  That might need to be made async also.

Comment: Yes I started removing them and do joins in my query to avoid multiple calls in the reader loop. Everything works now cheers

Comment: That's one of the trickier parts of doing the `async` / `await` pattern correctly.  It really does have to be "async all the way".  Even one blocking call can stall the UI.  Its far easier to do it right from the start, than to try and retro-fit an existing complex project.  Stephen Cleary has some fantastic blog posts on async / await if you want to learn more.  This is another great place to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx